# Where does nuget log detailed error message

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I created package and pushed it to local repository. Now when I'm trying to install package using Package Manager Console, I'm getting following error message

```
Installing 'MyPackage 1.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'MyPackage 1.0.0'.
Adding 'MyPackage 1.0.0' to TestConsoleApp.
Uninstalling 'MyPackage 1.0.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'MyPackage 1.0.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'MyDll'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  MyPackage
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2012. I found [this issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/407) on nuget.org, but I don't see any error message in `ActivityLog.xml`. I tried to run Visual Studio with `/log` switch but still nothing is getting logged. The issue is only with this package, I can successfully install other packages I created.

So my question is if nuget is logging more detailed message anywhere and if so where I can find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the $error object in the Package Manager Console. That usually has the exception and from that you can get the callstack.

From the console you may be able to get the full exception callstack the following:

```
$error[0].Exception.StackTrace
```

Otherwise take a look at the $error object and see what information it has that might be useful.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was lookng for!