# NuGet package installation fails with unspecified error

Tags: c#, c++, nuget

I've created a NuGet package that contains a C# (MyLibIF.dll) DLL that is a wrapper around a C++ DLL (MyLib.dll). They must be deployed next to each other.

This is NuSpec:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>MyLibIF.dll_x86</id>
    <version>8.0.0.1</version>
    <title>MyLib library for 32-bits</title>
    <authors>J.Doe</authors>
    <owners>Our Company</owners>
    <licenseUrl>https://localhost/license.html</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>https://localhost/GitWeb/MyLibIF.git</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://localhost/images/favicon.ico</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Library for some functionality and a type of integration</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2016</copyright>
    <tags>MyLib MyLibIF 32-bits</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\release\MyLibIF.dll" target="lib\net45"/>
    <file src="..\MyLib\Release\MyLib.dll" target="lib\net45"/> <!-- It's not a .NET dll, but should be alongside MyLibIF.dll in deployment -->
  </files>
</package>
```

This build the package just fine. When I deploy it used PowerShell for extra info I get this:
`

```
PM> install-package mylibif.dll_x86
Installing 'MyLibIF.dll_x86 8.0.0.1'.
Successfully installed 'MyLibIF.dll_x86 8.0.0.1'.
Adding 'MyLibIF.dll_x86 8.0.0.1' to ConsoleApplication1.
Uninstalling 'MyLibIF.dll_x86 8.0.0.1'.
Successfully uninstalled 'MyLibIF.dll_x86 8.0.0.1'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
install-package : Failed to add reference to 'MyLib'.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package mylibif.dll_x86
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand 
    PM>
```

`

The dreaded `NotSpecified`, this means absolutely nothing to me. 
I think the MyLibIF.dll is installing, but the MyLib.dll (the C++ one) is refused. I don't have enough NuGet knowledge to tackle this. 
Does anyone know what is happening here?

And on a side-note, how do you deploy when you don't care about the version of the .NET framework?

**UPDATE:**

I've updated the nuspec to contain references.

`<references>
    <reference file="MyLib.dll" />
    <reference file="MyLibIF.dll" />
</references>`

But it still fails with the same error. I can get it to work if I specify the target for `MyLib.dll` to `lib`. Ignoring the warning that NuGet gives it'll load the package into the following folder structure.

`.\packages\MyLibIF.dll_x86.8.0.0.1\lib\MyLib.dll
.\packages\MyLibIF.dll_x86.8.0.0.1\lib\net45\MyLibIF.dll`

So there is some intelligence that decides the MyLib.dll is not allowed inside net45...

Comment: You should be review this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672164/where-does-nuget-log-detailed-error-message

Comment: @Renzo: Unfortunately it doesn't provide extra meaningful info. The stack trace shows that the `NuGet.VisualStudio.VsProjectSystem.AddReference` fails. That I knew :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try embedding your C++ dll inside your .Net dll, this way you'll have only your .Net dll to deploy.

Costura.Fody may help you do that.

Talking about references : you shouldn't have to add reference to your c++ dll. There may be a cause for your issue.
read few lines above the "notspecified" : "Failed to add reference to 'MyLib'."

Go get a .Net project in VS and try to manually add a reference to your C++ lib : it shoud fail, and that's what your wrapper is for.

Take a look at these few elements, it should help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have look. One other way which will also work is creating a seperate NuGet package and have a dependency. This is how I got LM-X license library to work. Downside is the large number of packages (4) and the fact that the programmer has to choose the correct (32/64) version.

Comment: Yeah, large number of dependencies are a mess when trying to share work !
About the developper having to choose a specific version, developpers may be able to choose between 32/64, so that's not a really big issue to me :) ... But if you have a way to keep only one redist package that's still better